# Google Cloud Admin authentication

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Referring to the following link https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing . I've tried on the apikey but no success. The response from the API as follows;

```
//https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<projectid>/instances/<instanceid>/databases?key=<API_KEY>

{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Login Required.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

I've no issue with oAUth 2.0, hence would like to confirm if authorization through api key is no more supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested get information from the endpoint using only the API key and is not possible to retrieve information, since is necessary to use an authentication bearer.

I used these commands to get the databases information

```
export TOKEN=`gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

curl -X GET \
  https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[MY PROJECT ID]/instances/[MY INSTANCE NAME]/databases \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer '"$TOKEN"''
```

Since this request has sensitive data (non public) is necessary the OAuth token and the api key is not mandatory, as is stated on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing#authorizing-requests).

Looks like key parameter is not anymore necessary.